# Need clarification of "JNI WARNING: threadid=5 using env from threadid=3"

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-ndk

Full exception is below

```
12-24 08:59:24.800: WARN/dalvikvm(743): JNI WARNING: threadid=5 using env from threadid=3
12-24 08:59:24.800: WARN/dalvikvm(743):              in Ldalvik/system/NativeStart;.run ()V (GetObjectClass)
12-24 08:59:24.800: INFO/dalvikvm(743): "HeapWorker" daemon prio=5 tid=5 VMWAIT
12-24 08:59:24.800: INFO/dalvikvm(743):   | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x42998b90 self=0x156ad0
12-24 08:59:24.800: INFO/dalvikvm(743):   | sysTid=744 nice=0 sched=0/0 handle=1403536
12-24 08:59:24.800: INFO/dalvikvm(743):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
12-24 08:59:24.800: ERROR/dalvikvm(743): VM aborting
12-24 08:59:24.810: INFO/DEBUG(551): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
12-24 08:59:24.810: INFO/DEBUG(551): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic/:1.6/DRC76/13852:eng/test-keys'
12-24 08:59:24.810: INFO/DEBUG(551): pid: 743, tid: 744  >>> com.gamevil.testjni <<<
12-24 08:59:24.810: INFO/DEBUG(551): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr deadd00d
12-24 08:59:24.810: INFO/DEBUG(551):  r0 0000032c  r1 0000000c  r2 0000000c  r3 00000026
12-24 08:59:24.810: INFO/DEBUG(551):  r4 deadd00d  r5 00000000  r6 ad083e1c  r7 00000000
12-24 08:59:24.810: INFO/DEBUG(551):  r8 80601da0  r9 afe39dd4  10 100ffad0  fp 00000001
12-24 08:59:24.810: INFO/DEBUG(551):  ip ad083ef8  sp 100ffa48  lr afe13f0d  pc ad03b7fa  cpsr 20000030
12-24 08:59:24.849: INFO/Hollo-Jni(743): Caught signal with itimespec ..  1718
12-24 08:59:24.849: WARN/dalvikvm(743): JNI WARNING: threadid=7 using env from threadid=3
12-24 08:59:24.849: WARN/dalvikvm(743):              in Ldalvik/system/NativeStart;.run ()V (GetObjectClass)
12-24 08:59:24.849: INFO/dalvikvm(743): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=7 VMWAIT
12-24 08:59:24.849: INFO/dalvikvm(743):   | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x437541e8 self=0x157520
12-24 08:59:24.849: INFO/dalvikvm(743):   | sysTid=746 nice=0 sched=0/0 handle=1406176
12-24 08:59:24.849: INFO/dalvikvm(743):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
12-24 08:59:24.849: ERROR/dalvikvm(743): VM aborting
12-24 08:59:24.861: INFO/ActivityManager(575): Process com.gamevil.testjni (pid 743) has died.
```

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that you have 2 threads accessing the same JNIEnv object.

See:

- [Example of avoiding this error](http://books.google.com/books?id=-1eQ71mLj2cC&pg=PA255&lpg=PA255&dq=jni+warning+threadid+%22using+env+from%22&source=bl&ots=SqcFRB2yRb&sig=3qoO7ItgdBmrGvFZilxUSF5wsH8&hl=en&ei=GOYzS6GHIYbSlAf92b2qBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CBMQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=jni%20warning%20threadid%20%22using%20env%20from%22&f=false)
- [Same question answered elsewhere](http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/8717b7845bcc5758/01dcf592f1d772b6)

Comment: That's exactly what it means.  Note this is a Dalvik VM error, emitted when CheckJNI is enabled.

Comment: The first link - Example of avoiding this error - is dead.  It goes to a google books link that's not available.